# Splunk showing gateway timeout

Tags: dns, splunk

We're running Splunk in our environment. We can only access the Splunk instance via the IP address, but not the DNS address we have mapped to it.

For instance, we can go to this URL using the IP:

http://10.40.50.17:8000/en-US/app/launcher/home

Splunk is working fine. However if I go to:

http://splunk.mycompany.com:8000/en-US/app/launcher/home

I get a gateway timeout error:

> Gateway Timeout
>   Server error - server 10.40.50.17 is unreachable at this moment.
>   Please retry the request or contact your adminstrator.

I'm wondering where the issue may lie. Is this a problem with Splunk? Do I need to make Splunk aware of the DNS address that I'm giving it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check two places:

1. Your Windows DNS server, maybe there may be an issue there. Can you access other servers via DNS that are listed there? It could be an issue with the client you are on. Have you tried from another desktop or laptop?
2. In Splunk you can check your server.conf file
   http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Serverconf

Answer (score 0):

When you are able to access the splunk with IP address and port, means that splunk is working fine.

When you are not able to access the splunk with hostname and port, the hostname is not assigned to that particular ip in the local system. Try with other system to access with hostname.

Sol: Check the host file in local system.